# Alignment options with Draft.js in React

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

Cannot seem to find anything helpful on how to create **alignment options** in a RTE that I've built using React and Draft.js.  Their docs leave much to be desired.  Currently trying several variations of:

```
onClick={()=>setEditorState(RichUtils.toggleBlockType(editorState, 'align-center'))}
```

on my Button with no results.  I want to be able to align text blocks independently (ie. title in the center, content left, etc.). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You also need to add a Block Style with your styles. You can find the documentation here: https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-block-styling